# How can I prevent a clojure function from redefining?

Tags: clojure

I know I can use defonce for a normal def, but how can I prevent a clojure function from redefining?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use defonce to do that, but you must have some peculiar use case in mind - there is a reason there isn't a defn-once in clojure.core

```
(defonce fn-sym (fn [ ... ] .... ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was about to write what Joost said, but he beat me to it so I'll leave out that part.

If you really want a `defn-once`, do a source `source defn` and do something similar but exchange the `'def` somewhere close to the end with a `'defonce`.